# lenovo t420 /Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2

A screen has appeared with it saying at top GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1
Then in a box says

```
*Ubuntu,with Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
Ubuntu,with Linux 3.13.0.-43 generic (recovery mode)
3.13.0-40 generic
3.13.0-40 generic (recovery mode)
3.13.0-23-generic
23-   (Recovery mode)
```

My question is which one do I choose ? And it also continues to tell me there is problem

Internally could that mean maybe I didn't download it right ? Also I can't play my games on Facebook  flash will not download when I go to adobe site it gives me options on which to download I've tried all I'm new to Linux please help tell me what I'm doing wrong gosh I feel really stupid

Comment: Welcome to AU! It would be better if you don't post multiple unrelated issues as a single question. Please [edit] your question and remove the part about Flash Player, and either post a new question about it or, especially in this case, look for a similar existing question (e. g. [How to install standalone Adobe Flash Player on Trusty?](/q/563367)).

Answer (score 0):

A screen is asking which kernel to run for your system.Try the first one (3.13.0 -43), as it is the latest one with the newest improvements. If you have problems with it try 3.13.0-23 or 3.13.0.-40.

Recovery mode should be chosen when you have encountered any problems while working in the system.I think  is not necessary for you now.

For the flash problem, firstly I recommend you to check whether you have enabled Canonical partners repository.Also make sure you have installed ubuntu-restricted-extras.